# Sudden Failure in Keytab Authentication, Password Authentication Remains Functional

Tags: kerberos, mit-kerberos

Unexpectedly, we are encountering authentication failures when utilizing keytabs on our servers, while password-based authentication remains operational.

When executing the standard `kinit -kt princ.keytab princ@REALM.COM` command, everything functions as expected. However, issues arise when manually navigating to HBase or HDFS functions, with the following error message being displayed:

> "No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)"

When applying Python's exchangelib for connectivity RCW tests via `kinit princ@REALM.COM` with the future password, the process works seamlessly, allowing usage of both HDFS and HBase.

Attempts to manually create new keytabs have not resolved the issue, yielding the same results. A `klist` command returns correctly, confirming that I have a valid TGT ticket.

Comment: What does the KDC log when hbase attempts to use the keytab? (If it does at all.) What type of ticket cache are you using?